# Can you query new opportunity contact roles?

Tags: soql, opportunitycontactrole

Is it possible to use SOQL to list *new* opportunity contact roles added after a certain date? Ideally I'd like to schedule some apex that runs nightly, queries all new OCRs since the last run, then applies a change to the contacts -- but can this be done with just the new ones, or would it affect all OCRs each time it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Matt this is possible.
[image: SOQL on Opportunity Contact Role]

You can query opportunity Contact Role and have a scheduled batch to perform intended operations on newly created opportunityContactRole.
Make sure you apply proper filter like using CreatedDate > :LAST_RUN or CreatedDate = TODAY [Considering you are processing all records.]